# DAX Help - IF(ISBLANK(

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to show %, Blanks and Zeros separately within one formula.

At first I had a simple divide to work out the % of consistency:

```
[Number of Consistent] / [Num Overscore]
```

However it wasn't accurate for ones that have 0%, so I used an if formula:

```
IF ( [Number of Consistent] / [Num Overscore]), ( [Number of Consistent] / [Num Overscore] ), 0 )
```

This would put 0% if for the values even if they had blank in them, so I've tried adding an 'ISBLANK' formula in, but I'm having some trouble:

```
% Consistent = 
IF ( ISBLANK ( [Number of Consistent] / [Num Overscore], BLANK(), IF ( [Number of Consistent] / [Num Overscore],[Number of Consistent] / [Num Overscore],0 ) ) )
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The `DIVIDE` function may help.

```
% Consistent = 
DIVIDE ( 
    [Number of Consistent],
    [Num Overscore],
    BLANK()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! it comes back with the same kind of results i have two instances of blanks with one actually being blank and one being 0% however i have no way of distinguishing between the two only with the totals being effected.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you actually want to happen... `0%` isn't the same as `blank`. Please [edit] your question to show examples of your source data, with your expected output.

Comment: My results are broken down into areas and two separate types, for example Cardiff is showing as 0% and 14.29% with a total of 9.09% which indicates the first type for Cardiff is 0% as it affected my total. However, I have another area Bournemouth with 0% and 50% but the total is 50% because the first column is blank and therefore didn't impact the total. If I were to do the same formula in excel and pivot the data, it comes back with 0% and the #div/0 error whereas BI sees them both as the same both as blank or 0%. Apologies I hope this is clearer, thanks for the help its appreciated.

Comment: That's not clearer. Please, as I asked, [edit] your question, to show some actual data structure (rows and columns) and the expected outcome...